# How to pass parameters from Mouse-Event to a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, parameter-passing, mouseevent

I'm new in Python and I have the following problem:

This is the code I use to call the function *mouseclick*. But *mouseclick* needs the parameter *counter* (in my case).
**How do I pass** ***counter*** **at the function** ***mouseclick*** **at click on the label?**
This code here just passes the parameter *event*. **Where can I write the second parameter to pass?**

```
label1.bind('<Button-1>', mouseclick)
```

I tried this:

```
label1.bind('<Button-1>', mouseclick, counter)
```

and this:

```
label1.bind('<Button-1>', mouseclick(counter))
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: which gui is this?

Comment: what is the function `mouseclick`?

Comment: This is Tkinter

Comment: why are you passing a counter? You wouldn't be passing the variable, only the variable _value_. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy using `lambda`, you can bind the function call to `mouseclick` to a parameter, defining an "inlined" anonymous function

```
label1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event : mouseclick(event,counter))
```

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't work. I think it's the right way, but why it doesn't work. I get this error: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: What I have to do now to fix it? @Jean-François

Answer (score 1):

A common way to associate a variable with a function is to use a class instance. The nice thing about python class methods is that they keep a reference to their instance so they can be called later without specifically passing the instance.

```
class Counter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.counter += 1

mouseclick = Counter()
label1.bind('<Button-1>', mouseclick.on_click)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Tkinter you can add a variable `counter` to the `mouseclick`function like this:

```
tk = Tkinter.Tk()

class MyApp:

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.counter = 0
        self.myparent = parent

        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(tk,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=2)
        self.frame.pack()

        label=Tkinter.Label(self.frame,text="Click me")
        label.bind('<Button-1>', self.mouseclick)
        label.pack()

    def mouseclick(self, event):
            self.counter+=1
            print(self.counter)


myapp = MyApp(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```